# overwrite a specific ordered string from core data

Tags: swift, string, core-data, fetch, overwrite

In my swfit code below it saves a string and fetches it on the textfield. What I would like to do is overwrite the first value when the newBtn is pressed. So right now the first value is Lily Collins I type in the textfield Lily Ryan it should save as the first value in the attribute name. But right now no overwrite occurs. The overwriting should occur at  class func editName(user: User) -> Bool.

[image: gif]

[image]

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var txt = UITextField()
    var newBtn = UIButton()
    var user: [User]? = nil
    var deployment = 0
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [txt,newBtn ].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            txt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            txt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            txt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            txt.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            newBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: txt.bottomAnchor),
            newBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            newBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            newBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        coreDataHandler.saveObject(password: "Lily Collins")
        
        getText(imageNo: 0)
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func saveOverName() {
        
        
        user = coreDataHandler.fetchObject()
        
        coreDataHandler.editName(user: user![deployment])
        
        
    }
    
    func getText(imageNo:Int) {
        // first check the array bounds
        let info = helpText.shareInstance.fetchText()
        
        print("image count is", info.count)
        if info.count > imageNo {
            
            // check if the data is available
            
            
            if let imageData = info[imageNo].name
            {
                //    canvas.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                txt.text = String(imageData)
                
            } else {
                // no data
                print("data is empty Textss")
            }
        } else {
            // image number is greater than array bounds
            print("you are asking out of bounds")
        }
    }
    
}


class coreDataHandler : NSObject {
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    class func fetchObject() -> [User]?
    {
        let context = getContext()
        var user : [User]? = nil
        do {
            user = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
            
            
            return user
            
        } catch {
            return user
        }
        
    }
    class func saveObject( password: String) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        
        
        managedObject.setValue(password, forKey: "name")
        
        
        do{
            try context.save()
            return true
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    class func editName(user: User) -> Bool
    {
        
        let context = getContext()
        user.name.self
        
        
        
        do{
            
            try context.save()
            return true
        }
        catch{
            return false
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

class helpText: UIViewController{
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    static let shareInstance = helpText()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func saveName(data: String) {
        let imageInstance = User(context: context)
        imageInstance.name = data
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func fetchText() -> [User] {
        
        
        var fetchingImage = [User]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        
        do {
            
            fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [User]
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching the image")
        }
        
        return fetchingImage
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Where is the *action* method of the button? And why is `helpText` – by the way classes are supposed to be named uppercase – a subclass of `UIViewController` and `coreDataHandler` a subclass of `NSObject`? And be aware that Core Data records are saved unordered.

Comment: The action button is at  @objc func saveOverName() {

Comment: As you create the button in code you have to set target und action of the button explicitly.

Comment: I added a gif. Assume only 1 name is in core data. I need to add to the name and have it save to core data. I guess you could say append it. In the gif I add to the name then reload the view controller and then new name is saved in core data. I am looking to find a way to add to the string.